# spring compile error: cannot access ParameterizedTypeReference

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have been tasked with modifying an older Spring application and I need to add some rest calls.  When I tried to use RestTemplate I got a bunch of errors and ended upgrading from Spring 2.x to 4.x. I'm now getting:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-
plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project adddrop: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/jim/Documents/Dev/academic-addDrop-
web/src/main/java/edu/addDrop/web/FormPageController.java:[744,4] error: 
cannot access ParameterizedTypeReference
```

I ran an MVN dependency tree and saw that other jar files are using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE so I switched to that, but no luck. In my POM is have spring-core:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I presume this is a dependency issue but endless Googling has been fruitless.  I can't figure out where this class should be.

```
private ArrayList<String> getHarvardOpenSchools()
{
    RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("client_id", "3f36*********");
    headers.set("client_secret", "7251********");


    String url = "https://mit-cross-registration-v1-early-xreg.cloudhub.io/outgoing/stub/institutions/harvard/schools/xreg/open";

    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);

    // This is the offending line, 744
    rt.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);


    ResponseEntity<String> response = rt.getForEntity(url, String.class); 

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try
    {
        XregUniversity u = mapper.readValue(response.getBody(), XregUniversity.class);
        return u.getSchools();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }

}
```

Also, Eclipse is issuing this warning:

```
 The type org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

UPDATE:

If I switch to Spring 4.2.1.RELEASE I then get this compilation error:

```
 error: cannot access LabeledEnum
```

Comment: Question updated to include the code. The reason I suspect a dependency issue is from the research I have done it seems there is a colliding version of dependencies or else a missing one.

Comment: One thing that helps me.  Find the library(A) that depends on dependency(B).  I find the pom.xml file for library(A) that gives me a version about dependency(B).  I usually find that I have an older (or radically different newer) version of Dependency(B) in my pom.xml somewhere.  ex: https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-webflux/2.0.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-webflux-2.0.3.RELEASE.pom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ParameterizedTypeReference` is included in `spring-core` since 3.2, you should use a higher version of spring. use `spring 4` or `spring 5`.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I actually originally tried 4.2.1.RELEASE but went back down due to this error:  error: cannot access LabeledEnum

Comment: you can try to find LabeledEnum.class with the full package name in spring, if you can find it there may still be dependency issues.

Comment: It seems to have been deprecated as os Spring 3.0: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.17.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/enums/LabeledEnum.html

Comment: Yes, have you refered LabeledEnum in your project?

Comment: No, it seems to be related to RestTemplate.exchange().  None of these problems happen when I use RestTemplate.getForObject, but since I need to include headers I need to use exchange() and thats's when my progress hit a full stop.

Comment: It shouldn't be `exchange()`, that works perfectly in my case. I'm not sure, but try `4.3.2.RELEASE`.

Comment: Thanks, but same issue:   class file for org.springframework.core.enums.LabeledEnum not found

Comment: do a quick check on dependencies (e.g. by `mvn dependency:tree`) and check if ***all spring-related artifacts*** are of same version.  It seems to me that there are some outdated jars in your dependency list

Comment: Yes there are, and the pom for this project is a mess. I'm under the gun so a quicker way to get things going was to give up and use HttpClient instead of RestTemplate.  I'll clean up the pom and dependencies when I have time. Thanks everyone!  I'll mark this answer as accepted because it did answer the question, so thank you Dave.